# como mostrar dados do usuario em um card do bootstrap após o login ser validado

Tags: php, html, html5, mysqli, bootstrap-4

olá estou desenvolvendo um site de imobiliaria onde quero armazenar as informações do usuario após login, estou tentando usar session porem não estou tendo exito em armazenar minhas informações do usuario nas variaveis, na pagina após o login onde era para aparecero nome fica em branco, mas não aparece erro nenhum.
Alguém sabe um jeito simples e funcional de armazenar mostrar as informaçoes do usuario que fez login.
grato.

Comment: Cara inclua no mínimo o que vc já tem de código. como podemos te falar onde errou sem ver o que vc fez? Edita ai com o que vc tem até o momento

Answer (score 0):

Difícil dar uma solução sem ver parte do código, mas creio que você possa fazer dessa maneira:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login']; 
$_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['senha']; 
//  restante do código CRUD e etc
?>
```

ai para acessar os valores salvos na session basta iniciar a sessão em todas as paginas que irá utilizar como mostrado abaixo, mas é bom ressaltar que é não essa não é a melhor maneira de trafegar os dados do usuário, seria melhor você só salvar o id dele por exemplo e depois quando for necessário bucar os dados no banco.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        session_start();
    }
```